# Java HTTPException Return status code

Tags: java

please advise on the below scenario 
How can I handle Http Status code

```
try {
    validateUser(a,b);
} catch(HttpException he){
    response = new ResponseEntity<>(status code);
}

....

validateUser(String a, String b) throws HttpException {
    if(some condition) {
        throw new HttpException(); // I want throw set status code to 401 so that I can catch it up there in catch block 
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no HttpException in the standard Java API. So this comes from some third-party library. Which one? Have you read the documentation?

Comment: @slim but the OP is using HttpException. Not the same case. So not the same class.

Comment: You need to specify what library you are using, different libraries are doing things different ways.

Also the code you have is not compilable

Comment: I do not know what you want to do, but look at this questions it might enlighten you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39308475/getting-new-url-if-moved-permanently

Comment: public void validateUser(String a, String b) throws HttpException {     if(some condition) {         throw new HttpException(); // I want throw set status code to 401 so that I can catch it up there in catch block      } }

Comment: Since the method return type is void, I would like to throw HttpStatus code. Please advise

Comment: Repeating what you already said in the question won't help. Instead, **read** the comments and **answer** the questions.

Comment: I was able to resolve it

Comment: import java.xml.ws.http.HTTPException;  try {     validateUser(a,b); }  catch(HTTPException he){     response = new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.valueOf(he.getStatusCode())); } private void validateUser(String a, String b) throws HTTPException {     if(some condition) {         throw new HTTPException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());      } }

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import java.xml.ws.http.HTTPException; 

try {     
    validateUser(a,b); 
} catch(HTTPException he){     
    response = new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.valueOf(he.getStatusCode())); 
}

private void validateUser(String a, String b) throws HTTPException {     
    if(some condition) {         
        throw new HTTPException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());      
    } 
}
```